# UI Bootstrap typeahead list - don't auto select / highlight first item

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using UI bootstrap typeahead and it selects the first term by default. Here the [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/908).But since I am limiting the suggestions in the list, so all suggestions will not be in the list. Now if the user search for any term then automatically first term will be searched as its selected by default instead of the term entered. I want to search the entered term by default. Simply I want to remove the auto select feature.

To do this I found a hack on the github issue page to append the `$viewvalue` to the dropdown list:

```
typeahead="state for state in (states.length ? [$viewValue].concat(states) : [])"
```

[Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y7TpLS0deuagNPBpnZNq?p=preview)

Edit[working]:

And according to my need I modified it as:

```
typeahead="student for student in ((students.concat({name:$viewValue})) |filter:{name:$viewValue} | limitTo:8)"
```

Any other suggestions to remove the default auto select?

Answer (score 1):

Add  attribute `typeahead-focus-first=false`

Ref:
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/5720762-typeahead-focus-first-false-option-to-prevent-first-match-from-being-focused